# Confusion over List#foldLeft Behavior

Tags: scala

`List#foldLeft`, why is the following Scala 2.11.2 code:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).foldLeft(2) _ + _
res0: String => String = <function1>
```

returning a `<function1>`?

Additionally, why does the following result equal `<function1>5`?

```
scala> res0("5")
res2: String = <function1>5
```

Comment: foldLeft and foldRight are curried functions. They take two parameters (z and f) in two sets of parentheses instead of one: `def foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B` with z acting as seed to f.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've confused the compiler by trying to use infix notation (no parenthesis) and `_` placeholders and it's trying to curry it into a function.  This works for me:

```
scala> List(1,2,3).foldLeft(2) (_ + _)
res1: Int = 8
```